# Outlook asks for a password when trying to put a password to the windows session

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

hello I have a problem with a client, we need to put password on windows sessions of computers to open remote offices. When we put the password, microsoft outlook asks for the password of the mailbox (the session password is the same as the email password). We have empty the folders AppData \ Local \ Temp and AppData \ Local \ Microsoft \ Outlook \ (has the execution of the files ost) After redemarking on some post outlook goes back to work normally, on other after a certain time outlook redeconnects and asks for the password again. By the way if have remove the windows outlook session password this handshake will work fine.

Do you have an idea to fix the pb and that it works suddenly on all computers.

thank you in advance

Comment: Could I know how do you put password on windows sessions?

Comment: By This PC -> Manage -> Users -> Right Click -> Password define

Comment: Do you sign in Outlook and windows using same email account?

Comment: No windows session is a local session, but the password are the same

Comment: Not sure which setting is related. You may test this: Rename Outlook key to Outlook.old and then restart Outlook to reconfigure your account. (Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook)